# \href does not produce a clickable link

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, cv, hyperlink

I am using [Deedy's resume template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-resume/bjryvfsjdyxz) on overleaf to draft mine, and I created a few hyperlinks like this

```
\usepackage{hyperref} %added this as the last package

\namesection{John}{Doe}{ 
\urlstyle{same}\href{mailto:asdasd@gmail.com}{tarunn2799@gmail.com} | +12345| \urlstyle{same}\href{https://www.github.com/asd213}{GitHub} \\ 
%credentials changed, obviously
```

The email seems to work but the hyperlink to my github profile doesn't. It doesn't appear as a clickable link on the pdf.

Same happens in another subsection I created

```
\section{Side Projects}{

\href{https://www.github.com/asdsad}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name}     \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasdad}{name} \\

}
\sectionsep
```

In the above section, none of the links work they just appear as regular text.

Help me out here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add a complete (with your documentclass and the relevant packages you're using) but minimal example which reproduces your problem?

Comment: In particular, `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Side Projects}{
\href{https://www.github.com/asdsad}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name}     \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasdad}{name} \\
}
\end{document}` does not seem to have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your used class `deedy-resume-openfont` already called package `hyperref`, you do not need to call it a second time.

In your first code snippet is a closing `}` missing and with the following complete code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (16/9/2014)
%
% Original author:
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
%
% Original repository:
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lastupdated

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{John}{Doe}{%
  \urlstyle{same}\href{mailto:asdasd@gmail.com}{tarunn2799@gmail.com} |%
  +12345| %
  \urlstyle{same}\href{https://www.github.com/asd213}{GitHub} 
} % <===================================================================


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{MEng in Computer Science}
\location{Dec 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
\sectionsep

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{BS in Computer Science}
\location{May 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
College of Engineering \\
Magna Cum Laude\\
\location{ Cum. GPA: 3.83 / 4.0 \\
Major GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}
\sectionsep

\subsection{La Martiniere for Boys}
\location{Grad. May 2011|  Kolkata, India}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     LINKS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Side Projects}{% <=============================================
\href{https://www.github.com/asdsad}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name}     \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasd}{name} \\
\href{https://www.github.com/asdasdad}{name} \\
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Coursework}
\subsection{Graduate}
Advanced Machine Learning \\
Open Source Software Engineering \\
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\
Compilers + Practicum \\
Cloud Computing \\
Evolutionary Computation \\
Defending Computer Networks \\
Machine Learning \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Undergraduate}
Information Retrieval \\
Operating Systems \\
Artificial Intelligence + Practicum \\
Functional Programming \\
Computer Graphics + Practicum \\
{\footnotesize \textit{\textbf{(Research Asst. \& Teaching Asst 2x) }}} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Skills}
\subsection{Programming}
\location{Over 5000 lines:}
Java \textbullet{}   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascript \\
OCaml \textbullet{} Matlab \textbullet{} Rails \textbullet{} \LaTeX\ \\ 
\location{Over 1000 lines:}
C \textbullet{} C++ \textbullet{} CSS \textbullet{} PHP \textbullet{} Assembly \\
\location{Familiar:}
AS3 \textbullet{} iOS \textbullet{} Android \textbullet{} MySQL
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{Facebook}
\descript{| Software Engineer }
\location{Jan 2015 - Present | New York, NY}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Coursera}
\descript{| KPCB Fellow + Software Engineering Intern }
\location{June 2014 – Sep 2014 | Mountain View, CA}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item 52 out of 2500 applicants chosen to be a KPCB Fellow 2014.
\item Led and shipped Yoda - the admin interface for the new Phoenix platform. 
\item Full-stack developer - Wrote and reviewed code for JS using Backbone, Jade, Stylus and Require and Scala using Play
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Google}
\descript{| Software Engineering Intern }
\location{May 2013 – Aug 2013 | Mountain View, CA}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Worked on the YouTube Captions team, in Javascript and Python to plan, to design and develop the full stack to add and edit Automatic Speech Recognition captions. In production.
\item Created a backbone.js-like framework for the Captions editor.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Phabricator}
\descript{| Open Source Contributor \& Team Leader}
\location{Jan 2013 – May 2013 | Palo Alto, CA \& Ithaca, NY}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Phabricator is used daily by Facebook, Dropbox, Quora, Asana and more.
\item I created the Meme generator and more in PHP and Shell.
\item Led a team from MIT, Cornell, IC London and UHelsinki for the project.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Research}
\runsubsection{Cornell Robot Learning Lab}
\descript{| Researcher}
\location{Jan 2014 – Jan 2015 | Ithaca, NY}
Worked with \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ashesh/}{Ashesh Jain}} and \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/}{Prof Ashutosh Saxena}} to create \textbf{PlanIt}, a tool which  learns from large scale user preference feedback to plan robot trajectories in human environments.  
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Cornell Phonetics Lab}
\descript{| Head Undergraduate Researcher}
\location{Mar 2012 – May 2013 | Ithaca, NY}
Led the development of \textbf{QuickTongue}, the first ever breakthrough tongue-controlled game with \textbf{\href{http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/~tilsen/}{Prof Sam Tilsen}} to aid in Linguistics research. 
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Awards} 
\begin{tabular}{rll}
2014         & top 52/2500  & KPCB Engineering Fellow\\
2014         & 1\textsuperscript{st}/50  & Microsoft Coding Competition, Cornell\\
2013         & National  & Jump Trading Challenge Finalist\\
2013     & 7\textsuperscript{th}/120 & CS 3410 Cache Race Bot Tournament  \\
2012     & 2\textsuperscript{nd}/150 & CS 3110 Biannual Intra-Class Bot Tournament \\
2011     & National & Indian National Mathematics Olympiad (INMO) Finalist \\
\end{tabular}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Publications} 
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5em} % Couldn't get this working from the .cls file
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{publications}
\nocite{*}

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

I get the clickable result (please see that you have to move your mouse cursor on `name` to get the resulting and active link showed):

[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry, that was just a typographical error in the post. The {} already exists in the original latex file, it still doesn't work.